# Hiding multiple columns on another sheet: Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

got hugely stuck on what seemed a simple task... get type mismatch error when I try to hide **multiple** columns using this code..

any better suggestions?

Regards,

```
Sub Hider()

        Sheets("Data Source").Columns("O:AK").Hidden = False

        Sheets("Data Source").Columns("W, V").Hidden = True

    end sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
Sub Hider()

    Sheets("Data Source").Columns("O:AK").Hidden = False

    Sheets("Data Source").Range("W:W, V:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

end sub
```

Comment: many thanks, this appears to be working.. weird I'm sure i tried this approach bu eh!

Comment: +1 for solution that worked for non-contiguous range

Answer (score 0):

Use

`Sheets("Data Source").Columns("V:W").Hidden = True`

instead of

`Sheets("Data Source").Columns("W, V").Hidden = True`

Comment: perhaps i used a poor choice of columns.. i'm not looking to hide ranges of columns but non-contiguous individual columns